# Sequelize how to check if entry exists in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to check if entry with specific ID exists in the database using Sequelize in Node.js

```
  function isIdUnique (id) {
    db.Profile.count({ where: { id: id } })
      .then(count => {
        if (count != 0) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
  }
```

I call this function in an if statement but the result is always undefined

```
if(isIdUnique(id)){...}
```

Comment: I'd use `db.Profile.findOne` with `options.rejectOnEmpty` to throw an error, and then place the success callback in a preceding `.then` and an error cb (not found, etc.) in `.catch`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update:** see the [answer which suggests using `findOne()` below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42737209/771848). I personally prefer; this answer though describes an alternative approach.

You are *not returning* from the `isIdUnique` function:

```
function isIdUnique (id) {
    return db.Profile.count({ where: { id: id } })
      .then(count => {
        if (count != 0) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}

isIdUnique(id).then(isUnique => {
    if (isUnique) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you associate your models as child objects of the main sequelize/db object?

Comment: Using count means it will go through all records in the database every time. It would be more efficent to use findOne() as in Jalal's answer below

Answer (score 53):

I don't prefer using **count** to check for record existence. Suppose you have similarity for hundred in million records why to count them all if you want just to get boolean value, true if exists false if not?

**findOne** will get the job done at the first value when there's matching.

```
const isIdUnique = id =>
  db.Profile.findOne({ where: { id} })
    .then(token => token !== null)
    .then(isUnique => isUnique);
```

Comment: How do you load Sequelize models as child objects of the `db` object?

Comment: Where exactly do we put this piece of code? Can you share a full example?

Comment: what is this extra chaining of Promise `.then(isUnique => isUnique)` for?

Comment: we should select needed attributes for better performance `findOne({where : {id} , attributes: ['id]} )`

Answer (score 3):

You can count and find.

```
    Project
  .findAndCountAll({
     where: {
        title: {
          [Op.like]: 'foo%'
        }
     },
     offset: 10,
     limit: 2
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.count);
    console.log(result.rows);
  });
```

[Doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#-findandcountall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database-returns-both-data-and-total-count) link, v5 Beta Release

Answer (score 3):

I found [the answer by @alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480661/630530) to be unreliable in some instances, so I tweaked the logic:

```
function isIdUnique (id, done) {
  db.Profile.count({ where: { id: id } })
  .then(count => {
    return (count > 0) ? true : false
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending @Jalal's answer, if you're very conscious about performance implications while maintaining a simple Sequelize structure and you do not need the row data, I suggest you only request one column from the database. Why waste bandwidth and time asking the database to return all columns when you won't even use them?

```
const isIdUnique = id =>
  db.Profile.findOne({ where: { id }, attributes: ['id'] })
    .then(token => token !== null)
    .then(isUnique => isUnique);
```

The `attributes` field tells Sequelize to only request the `id` column from the database and not sending the whole row's content.

Again this may seem a bit excessive but at scale and if you have many columns that hold a lot of data, this could make a giant difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

As Sequelize is designed around promises anyway, [alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480661/1107110) probably makes most sense, but for the sake of offering an alternative, you can also pass in a callback:

```
function isIdUnique (id, done) {
    db.Profile.count({ where: { id: id } })
      .then(count => {
        done(count == 0);
      });
  }
}

isIdUnique(id, function(isUnique) {
  if (isUnique) {
    // stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution. I tried it and it works well.

```
const isIdUnique = async (id, model) => {
    return await model.count({ where: { id: id } });
};
        
const checkExistId = await isIdUnique(idUser, User);
console.log("checkExistId: ", checkExistId);
```